# Defining 控える and 控えている

Tags: words

[`控える`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E6%8E%A7%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/UTF-8/?pg=1) as far as I can tell behaves more predictably than [`控えている`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E6%8E%A7%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B/UTF-8/) in that it generally seems to mean "to refrain" and "to make notes" (as in `電話番号を控える`.)

However, `控えている` seems to mean many more things including "expecting (a baby)", "to be soon", "waiting (for)", "facing", "contend with" and "abstain from":

> 彼女は出産を控えているの？
>   Is she expecting （a child）?
>
> ちょうど1年後に控えている
>   be just a year away.
>
> 使者が次の間に控えている
>   The messenger is waiting in the next room.
>
> 彼の別荘は後ろに山を控えている
>   There is a mountain behind his country cottage.
>
> その会社には幾多の難問題が控えている
>   The company has many difficulties to contend with.
>
> 彼は健康上の理由から肉を控えている。
>   He abstains from meat for health reasons.

Would I be able to ask how to define `控える` and `控えている`, how they have come to mean so many things and whether there's a way of determining what `控えている` means in a given context?

Comment: In the second example,`主語を`? What is that?

Comment: @sawa I was wondering the same thing, that's the way it was written at [Space ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%A91%E5%B9%B4%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%AB%E6%8E%A7%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B/UTF-8/)

Comment: Don't trust the internet (including this website) too much. It is up to you what to believe and what to think.

Comment: @sawa I did look in a paper dictionary, but I couldn't find anything conclusive. Anyway, thanks for clearing up some of the core meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two dictionaries: [goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/62692/m0u/%E6%8E%A7%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/) and [alc](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E6%8E%A7%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/UTF-8/?pg=1). (Any good Japanese-English dictionaries that I can reference here? I always use a Japanese-Japanese one. The translation are not very good. However, the examples in alc are excellent, though not 100% correct.)

The meaning of 控える can be "waiting/saying behind(for something)", or "to refrain", or "to make notes", or more. And 控えている is formed by 控え+ている, and "ている" here means something like "in the state of".

As for the examples:

> ```
> ちょうど1年後に控えている
> be just a year away（主語を）
> ```

It means the phrase can be used as "**卒業を**ちょうど一年後に控えている", "**Graduation** is just a year away".

Answer (score 2):

With or without `ている`, the core meaning does not change. It means 'waiting/staying behind (for something)'